# gke cert manager certificate in progress

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

Im trying to make my google services more secure by moving from http to https. I've been follwing the cert-manager documentation to get it working.

https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/google/

I can't install helm on the cluster nor nginx ingress that's why im using the dns01 challenge instead of the http01.

I installed cert-manager with regular manifests v0.11.0.

After creating a dns admin service account, i used this yaml to create the issuer :

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: example-issuer
spec:
  acme:
    email: email@gmail.com
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      # Secret resource used to store the account's private key.
      name: example-issuer-account-key
    # Add a single challenge solver, HTTP01 using nginx
    solvers:
      - dns01:
          clouddns:
            project: my-project-id
            # This is the secret used to access the service account
            serviceAccountSecretRef:
              name: clouddns-dns01-solver-svc-acct
              key: key.json
```

and my certificate object :

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: example-com
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretName: example-com-tls
  issuerRef:
    # The issuer created previously
    name: example-issuer
  commonName: my-domain.com
  dnsNames:
    - my-domain.com
    - www.my-domain.com
```

After applying these files, i had this results :

```
$ kubectl describe issuer
Name:         example-issuer
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"cert-manager.io/v1alpha2","kind":"Issuer","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"example-issuer","namespace":"default"},"spec...
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
Kind:         Issuer
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2019-11-28T15:00:33Z
  Generation:          1
  Resource Version:    306180
  Self Link:           /apis/cert-manager.io/v1alpha2/namespaces/default/issuers/example-issuer
  UID:                 d3d1f66e-11ef-11ea-856a-42010a8401a2
Spec:
  Acme:
    Email:  email@gmail.com
    Private Key Secret Ref:
      Name:  example-issuer-account-key
    Server:  https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    Solvers:
      dns01:
        Clouddns:
          Project:  my-project-id
          Service Account Secret Ref:
            Key:   key.json
            Name:  clouddns-dns01-solver-svc-acct
Status:
  Acme:
    Last Registered Email:  email@gmail.com
    Uri:                    https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/11671464
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2019-11-28T15:00:34Z
    Message:               The ACME account was registered with the ACME server
    Reason:                ACMEAccountRegistered
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Ready
Events:                    <none>

$ kubectl get certificates -o wide
NAME          READY   SECRET            ISSUER           STATUS                                                                AGE
example-com   False   example-com-tls   example-issuer   Waiting for CertificateRequest "example-com-1030278725" to complete   49m

$ kubectl get CertificateRequest -o wide
NAME                     READY   ISSUER           STATUS                                                                                            AGE
example-com-1030278725   False   example-issuer   Waiting on certificate issuance from order default/example-com-1030278725-1017944607: "pending"   50m
```

Comment: DNS01 validation uses TXT records to validate. Go to Google Cloud DNS. Find your domain. Do you see any `_acme-challenge` records? If yes, what are the TTLs set to? If no, double check that the service account has permissions to manage the DNS server.

Comment: After checking tha IAM interface, the service is a dns administrator https://ibb.co/87Z5KMK but in when i went to the Google Cloud DNS i didn't find any record

Comment: No records were created. What does that tell you? Either no permissions to modify your DNS server or invalid configuration setup. What does Stackdriver tell you? There is an error message somewhere that will point to the problem.

Comment: After checking Stackdriver, i found this warning [message: "Error presenting challenge: No matching GoogleCloud domain found for domain mamdouni-apps.com." ]. well the domain was created via google.domains.com and it works fine  with my http ingress. i checked it : http://mamdouni-apps.com/ , http://mamdouni-apps.com/v2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to complete DNS01 challenges for a domain managed by Google Domains DNS Servers. This is not possible at this time.

Google Domains DNS is not Google Cloud DNS. You cannot use Cert Manager for automatic DNS01 challenges with Google Domains. There is no API to setup TXT records in Google Domains. There is a supported API for Cert Manager for Google Cloud DNS.

My recommendation: move your domain's DNS servers to Cloud DNS.

Comment: ok it's more clear for me now. I appreciate your help thank you John. I will use the http01 challenge for now until we move to the Google Cloud DNS.