# Istio Gateway Fail To Connect Via HTTPS

Tags: https, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, istio, cert-manager

Deployments in a GKE cluster with Istio is working correctly via `HTTP`. But when i tried to secure it with cert-manager with following resources, HTTPS request fails state like so on curl

```
`Immediate connect fail for 64:ff9b::2247:fd8a: Network is unreachable
* connect to 34.71.253.138 port 443 failed: Connection refused`.
```

What should i do to make it work with HTTPS as well.

ClusterIssuer with following configuration

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  acme:
    # The ACME server URL
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # Email address used for ACME registration
    email: iprocureservers@iprocu.re
    # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    solvers:
    # ACME DNS-01 provider configurations
    - dns01:
        # Google Cloud DNS
        clouddns:
          # Secret from the google service account key
          serviceAccountSecretRef:
            name: cert-manager-credentials
            key: gcp-dns-admin.json
          # The project in which to update the DNS zone
          project: iprocure-server
```

Certificate configuration like so, which made a certifiate in a Ready:True state

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha3
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  secretName: letsencrypt-staging
  commonName: "*.iprocure.tk"
  dnsNames:
  - '*.iprocure.tk'
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-staging
    kind: ClusterIssuer
```

And lastly a Gateway

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: iprocure-gateway
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: false
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - "*"
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: letsencrypt-staging
```

If i do, `kubectl describe certificate -n istio-system`

```
    Name:         letsencrypt-staging
    Namespace:    istio-system
    Labels:       <none>
    Annotations:  <none>
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Kind:         Certificate
    Metadata:
    Creation Timestamp:  2020-10-13T13:32:37Z
    Generation:          1
    Resource Version:    28030994
    Self Link:           /apis/cert-manager.io/v1/namespaces/istio-system/certificates/letsencrypt-staging
    UID:                 ad838d28-5349-4aaa-a618-cc3bfc316e6e
    Spec:
    Common Name:  *.iprocure.tk
    Dns Names:
        *.iprocure.tk
    Issuer Ref:
        Kind:       ClusterIssuer
        Name:       letsencrypt-staging-clusterissuer
    Secret Name:  letsencrypt-staging-cert-secret
    Status:
    Conditions:
        Last Transition Time:  2020-10-13T13:35:05Z
        Message:               Certificate is up to date and has not expired
        Reason:                Ready
        Status:                True
        Type:                  Ready
    Not After:               2021-01-11T12:35:05Z
    Not Before:              2020-10-13T12:35:05Z
    Renewal Time:            2020-12-12T12:35:05Z
    Revision:                1
    Events:                    <none>
```

Running `kubectl get certificates -o wide -n istio-system`, yields

```
NAME                  READY   SECRET                            ISSUER                              STATUS                                          AGE
letsencrypt-staging   True    letsencrypt-staging-cert-secret   letsencrypt-staging-clusterissuer   Certificate is up to date and has not expired   17h
```

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/certmanager/#istio-gateway), `my.example.com # This should match a DNS name in the Certificate`. Could you try to change hosts from `*` to `'*.iprocure.tk'` in your gateway and check if it works?

Comment: @Jakub Thank you for your reply. I did the changes you requested, deleted both certificate and gateway then reapply them, but no change. `http://staging.iprocure.tk` without https works, but when i do `https://staging.iprocure.tk` it says `This site can’t be reachedstaging.iprocure.tk refused to connect.`

Comment: 1.Could you add output from `kubectl describe certificate -n istio-system` or `kubectl get certificates -n istio-system -o wide` to your question? 2.Could you check If you run `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`, are there multiple cert-manager pods? 3.What is the istio version?

Comment: @Jakub, i have added the output of `kubectl describe certificate -n istio-system` as you requested.

Comment: About running `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`, yes it runs and displays list of pods across all namespaces

Comment: Anything wrong in `kubectl get certificates -o wide -n istio-system`? I'm asking because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59092594/gke-cert-manager-certificate-in-progress). As for istio, I don't see any errors here, the only thing that comes to mind is that you use dns01 and in most tutorials they use http01. What is the istio version, it's addon or on-prem?

Comment: @Jakub, I'm using GKE 1.17.12-gke.500 and enabled ISTIO, so i guess its Istio 1.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223010/discussion-between-yunus-einsteinium-and-jakub).

Comment: @Jakub, Thank you for guiding me in the right direction. Using the OSS Istio, not the GKE one, is the way to go! I managed to make HTTPS work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

I assume that https wasn't working because of the [requirements](https://istio.io/v1.4/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-certmgr/#before-you-begin) which have to be enabled if you want to use cert-menager with istio in older versions.

### Solution

As @Yunus Einsteinium mentioned in comments

> Thank you for guiding me in the right direction. Using the OSS Istio, not the GKE one, is the way to go! I managed to make HTTPS work!

So the solution here was to use [OOS istio installed with istioctl](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/istioctl/) instead of the older istio gke addon.